# Azure SQL DW CTAS of over 102,400 rows to one distribution doesn't automatically compress

Tags: azure-synapse

I thought the way columnstores worked was that if you bulk load over 102,400 rows into one distribution of a columnstore, it would automatically compress it. I'm not observing that in Azure SQL DW.

I'm doing the following CTAS statement:

```
create table ColumnstoreDemoCTAS
WITH (CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, DISTRIBUTION=HASH(Column1))
AS
select top 102401 cast(1 as int) as Column1, f.*
from FactInternetSales f
cross join sys.objects o1
cross join sys.objects o2
```

Now I check the status of the columnstore row groups:

```
select t.name
,NI.distribution_id
,CSRowGroups.state_description
,CSRowGroups.total_rows
,CSRowGroups.deleted_rows
FROM sys.tables AS t
JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON t.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.pdw_index_mappings AS IndexMap
    ON i.object_id = IndexMap.object_id
    AND i.index_id = IndexMap.index_id
JOIN sys.pdw_nodes_indexes AS NI
    ON IndexMap.physical_name = NI.name
    AND IndexMap.index_id = NI.index_id
LEFT JOIN sys.pdw_nodes_column_store_row_groups AS CSRowGroups
    ON CSRowGroups.object_id = NI.object_id 
    AND CSRowGroups.pdw_node_id = NI.pdw_node_id
    AND CSRowGroups.distribution_id = NI.distribution_id
    AND CSRowGroups.index_id = NI.index_id    
WHERE t.name = 'ColumnstoreDemoCTAS'
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4 desc;
```

I end up with one OPEN rowgroup with 102401 rows. Did I misunderstand this behavior of columnstores? Is Azure SQL DW different?

I see the same behavior if I do an bulk insert from SSIS of the same number of rows all as one buffer.

I tried Drew's suggestion of inserting over 6.5 million rows and I still end up with all OPEN row stores:

```
create table ColumnstoreDemoWide
WITH (CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX, DISTRIBUTION=HASH(Column1))
AS
select top 7000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.ProductKey) as Column1, f.*
from FactInternetSales f
cross join sys.objects o
cross join sys.objects o2
cross join sys.objects o3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a defect in the service. The fix is currently being rolled out. If you try this out on Japan West for example you will see that the behaviour is as you would expect.

Comment: Right you are @JRJ. Thanks! I was able to confirm my 102401 row repro above now ends up compressed after the CTAS. On my Azure SQL DW if I run "select @@version" I get back 10.0.8224.5 so I assume you can know you have the fix when your version number hits that build or newer. Thanks.

Comment: That is correct Greg @@version 10.0.8224.5 is the version that includes this fix.

Answer (score 2):

placing your data in a clustered columnstore will not decrease the number of rows returned.  Instead, it will compress the data stored so that it takes up less space on disk. This will mean that less data is moved for queries and you will be charged less for storage, but your results will stay the same.  That being said, your data is currently residing in a deltastore, so you will not see any compression.  Due to SQL DW's architecture we separate the data into a number of groups under the covers.  This allows us to more easily parallelize computations and scale, but also means that each group will have it's own columnstore/deltastore, so you will need to load more rows to get the compression benefits.

In addition to the distribution structure there is a difference in thresholds for SQL Server when compared to SQL Data Warehouse. For DW the threshold was 1,048,576 until a defect was resolved as @JRJ describes. Now Azure SQL DW's threshold is 120,400 like the rest of the SQL family. Once your rows in a distribution exceeds this you should see that your rows are compressed.

You can find a bit more information on loading into a columnstore here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn935008.aspx

Comment: Drew, thank you for your time! I understand the concept of columnstore compression and delta stores. My question is why (as that document you referenced states should happen) Azure SQL DW doesn't seem to automatically compress a row group after a bulk load of more than 102400 rows into a single distribution. Based upon your comments, I inserted 7 million rows into the table and now I have 60 even distributions of at least 116,000 rows each and all are still OPEN not compressed. Is this an Azure SQL DW bug? I will edit my question with the exact query I used to insert 7 million rows.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for following up here, I misspoke in my earlier comment.  In addition to the distribution structure there is a difference in thresholds for SQL Server when compared to SQL Data Warehouse.  For DW the threshold is 1,048,576.  Once your rows in a distribution exceeds this you should see that your rows are compressed.

Comment: thanks. If you will edit your answer I'm happy to accept it. How can I help get the docs fixed on that link you provided and in the Azure docs? Shall I submit feedback on those pages? This is a Very important nuance that departs from SQL and PDW.

Comment: Updated the answer to match the info from @JRJ about the recent fix.